# Windows 7 - from ip to domain

Tags: windows

I use Windows 7, and enter to a website, which need to find an ip (with port 8080). It doesn't find it.

I want to tell him that this ip belong to a domain (http://wargra....)

There is a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file called "hosts" in the folder "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" using notepad or a similar program.

See the line 127.0.0.1 localhost
That line means that if you type localhost it has to go to IP 127.0.0.1 so simply add a line for your IP and domain in the same fashion.

That will only work for you though, if you need everyone to beable to access the server that goes by the IP you are talking about you need to PURCHASE a domain at godaddy or similar and point the DNS to the IP of the server.